# Martingales: What does $F_{n-1}$ measurable mean compared to $F_{n}$ measurable?

Tags: martingales

My workbook gives the following property for Conditional Expectation and martingale:

- **Measurability**:

  If $Y_n$ is "$F_n$ measurable", then:

  $E[Y_n~|~F_n] = Y_n$

Let's say I have a Stochastic Process $\{A_n, n\ge 0\}$ that is "$F_{n-1}$" measurable?  (My rule is written for "$F_n$ measurable", so I'm wondering how to handle this case when $A_n$ is $F_{n-1}$ measurable.)

For Example, i'm assuming the following relationship holds if $A_n$ is "$F_{n-1}$" measurable?  (but, no idea if its correct):

$$E[A_n | F_{n-1}] = A_n???$$

And, let $n = m+1~~~ \Rightarrow ~~~n-1 = m$

$$E[A_{m+1} | F_m] = A_{m+1}???$$

Does this make any sense?

---

Here's where I need know how the "$F_{n-1}$ measurability" works:

**Doob's decomposition**:  Let $X = \{X_n, n \ge 0\}$ be a sub-martingale with respect to $F_n$.  Then, there exists a martingale $M = \{M_n, n \ge 0\}$ and a process $A = \{A_n, n \ge 0\}$ such that:

1. M is a martingale with respect to $F_n$
2. A is an increasing process $A_{n+1} \ge A_n$
3. **$A_n$ is "$F_{n-1}$ measurable" for all n.** $\Leftarrow$
4. $X_n = M_n + A_n$

Note, condition 3 says $F_{n-1}$ measurable instead of $F_n$ measurable.

Answer (score 2):

A process $A_n$ such that $A_n$ is $F_{n-1}$ measurable for each $n$ is often said to be **predictable**.  You are quite correct that if $A_n$ is a predictable process then $E[A_n \mid F_{n-1}] = A_n$; I don't see why you would doubt it?  And of course it is equally true that $E[A_{m+1} \mid F_m] = A_{m+1}$.

Note that martingales typically do *not* have this property; indeed, you can show that if $A_n$ is a martingale which is predictable then it is constant with respect to time, e.g. $A_0 = A_1 = A_2 = \dots$ almost surely.